# Bootstrap 4 dropdown use custom container

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, sass, bootstrap-4, megamenu

I am building a Megamenu based on Bootstrap 4 dropdown.

I want to use a custom container e.g `<div class="dropdown-container">`, which show/hide the dropdown content. Instead of using Bootstrap  `<div class="dropdown-menu">`.

Because with positioning the Megamenu I have problems because of `style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;"` added by Bootstrap when using `<div class="dropdown-menu">`.

I tried:

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function () {
    $('.dropdown-container').toggleClass('show')
  });
```

But when I click another menu item it's not showing/hiding anymore?

This is the markup.

```
    <li class="nav-item expanded dropdown dropdown-megamenu">
            <a href="/test" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MegaMenu test link <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
    <!-- Dropdown Megamenu content  -->
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item expanded dropdown dropdown-megamenu">
            <a href="/test" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MegaMenu test link two<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
    <!-- Dropdown Megamenu content two  -->
    </div>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I attach my class `megamenu` to the `dropdown-menu` class with the following CSS:

```
.megamenu {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 70px, 0px) !important;
  padding: 30px;
  a {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

edit: turns out, Bootstrap arbitrarily determines whether or not to apply PopperJS styles based on whether or not a parent element has the `navbar` class. See [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23378) issue